# How does alternative splicing actually work?

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology

How do two identical pre-mRNA molecules give rise to two different mRNA molecules after alternative splicing? They contain the same introns and exons and thus same splicing enhancers and silencers

Is it just a case of what proteins/snRNA happen bind to the mRNA first?

Answer (score 1):

A mRNA molecule is composed of introns and exons. All introns are removed before translation occurs*. However, sometimes exons are also cut. This leads to different mRNA molecules, and therefore, different proteins. This image gives very good summaries in my opinion ([source](https://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJMra012240?HITS=10&hits=10&FIRSTINDEX=0&searchid=1036789285973_23570&stored_search=&journalcode=nejm&RESULTFORMAT=&sortspec=PUBDATE_SORTDATE%20desc%20Score%20desc&maxtoshow=&fulltext=Genomic%20Medicine)): [image: Alternative splicing with translation]

According the National Library of Medicine, the different mRNA strands are called transcript variants, splice variants, or isoforms. I admit that I do not understand how a cell 'decides' when to use one variant over another. [This](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4360811/) free article is on that very topic, but it is beyond me. To quote the abstract:

> Regulation of alternative splicing is a complicated process in which
> numerous interacting components are at work, including cis-acting
> elements and trans-acting factors, and is further guided by the
> functional coupling between transcription and splicing. Additional
> molecular features, such as chromatin structure, RNA structure and
> alternative transcription initiation or alternative transcription
> termination, collaborate with these basic componentsto generate the
> protein diversity due to alternative splicing.

*Some may argue that this is not true. There is a mode of alternative splicing where introns are left in called intron retention. Personally, I think that a region that is sometimes removed from the mRNA and sometimes left in should be classified as an exon, so intron retention is the results of misclassifying an exon as an intron rather than a genuine biological phenomenon.

Comment: But presumably the poster knows the part of your answer that says what alternative splicing is, and you haven’t answered his question which relates to how this is controlled, except from the quotation which you admit not to understanding. In fact the quotation says nothing of substance, but is so much hand waving.

Comment: It was not clear to me how familiar the OP was with alternative splicing, so I provided a basic overview  and a link to very detailed paper that went over the details I was not confident trying to explain. If they were new to the topic, then they have their basic answer. If they were knowledgeable in the topic already, then they have a great resource on where they can do more research. If you dislike my approach, perhaps you should leave an answer to the question.